# How to get the Nth occurrence of a day of the week for a given month?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

The week of month does not define this value.
The shift between the starting week and starting month causes the problem in most cases.

Is there any python lib or algorithm to calculate this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate this by looping over the days of the month and counting whether you've come across that *n*th weekday:

```
import datetime

def get_n_weekday(year, month, day_of_week, n):
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(1, 32):
        try:
            d = datetime.date(year, month, i)
        except ValueError:
            break
        if d.isoweekday() == day_of_week:
            count += 1
        if count == n:
            return d
    return None
```

For example: `get_n_weekday(2016, 1, 1, 1)` = first Monday of January 2016 which is `datetime.date(2016, 1, 4)`.

This uses [`date.isoweekday()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) which means Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7.

Answer (score 1):

Two more simpler solutions than Simeon's answer:

```
def f1(day_of_month):
    ret = None    
    if ( day_of_month % 7 == 0 ):
        ret = day_of_month/7
    else:
        ret = (day_of_month//7) + 1
    return ret       


def f2(day_of_month):
    actual_day = day_of_month
    counter = 0
    while actual_day > 0:
        actual_day = actual_day - 7
        counter = counter + 1
    return counter
```